# replace row values in a single column pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I keep getting warning "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame". 
How could I fix it? Any  alternative

```
 //check for NAN
 //capitalise first letter
//assign 'Male' for 'm',
//assign 'Female for 'f'

myDataFrame.to_csv('new_H.csv')
genderList = myDataFrame.loc[:,"Gender"] //extract Gender column

for i in range(0, len(genderList)):

    if type(genderList[i]) == float:   #check for empty spaces
         genderList[i] = 'NAN'
    elif genderList[i].startswith('f'):
          genderList[i] = 'Female'    
    elif genderList[i].startswith('m'):
          genderList[i] = 'Male'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
for row in myDataFrame.itertuples():
    if type(row["Gender"]) == float:
        row["Gender"] = 'NAN'
    elif row["Gender"].startswith('f'):
        row["Gender"] = 'Female'
    elif row["Gender"].startswith('m'):
        row["Gender"] = 'Male'
```

The line `genderList = myDataFrame.loc[:,"Gender"]` cause warning since you are assigning a piece of your data frame, which could result a copy so update may not be applied to original dataframe. In code above, I used `itertuples` method which is a more "correct" way to iterate through rows in pandas. If you want to perform an action on a specific row, you do need to create a slice of it first - you just update the value of this column in every row.

From what I see, you goal is to replace values on Gender based on previous values. In that case I recommend to check pandas's `replace` method which is made for that exact reason together with `filter`. But, since your filter is quite simple, you can do the following:

```py
myDataFrame[myDataFrame["Gender"].str.contains('^f')] = "Female"
```

To update all female. I used slicing of dataframe (`myDataFrame[...]`) and the condition is `myDataFrame["Gender"].str.contains('^f')`.

Comment: I used ```myDataFrame['Gender'] = myDataFrame['Gender'].replace('f', 'Female')``` and it worked . However, I can't find a way to replace White Spaces with NaN . This will not work ```myDataFrame['Gender'].apply(lambda element: element.replace('', np.NaN))```

Comment: @bibscy Are you trying to replace white spaces with nan? cause in code you checked values is float, and right now your replace has no chars in it (`replace('', np.NaN)`).

Comment: Yes, I want to replace white spaces with nan. To do this also tried this and  it still does not work ```myDataFrame['Gender'] = myDataFrame['Gender'].replace('', np.nan)```

Comment: It works for me. Notice in your comment you wrote `''` and not `' '` (missing white space). Maybe it is the problem? also, are you sure it's white space?

Comment: Just to clarify, I want to replace empty string which  in theory has a length of zero. This is not working  ```myDataFrame['Gender'] = myDataFrame['Gender'].replace('', 'NaN')``` How do I fix this?

Comment: @bibscy ok then. Empty is not the same as white spaces, and that is what confused me. To fill empty values in your dateframe you can use `fillna` method: `myDataFrame['Gender'].fillna('NaN')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215093/discussion-between-bibscy-and-roim).